# Is it dangerous to store a JWT in a Javascript-accessible cookie

Tags: security, cookies, jwt

In other words, is it dangerous to have a JWT, which doesn't contain any sensitive info, in a cookie **without** the httponly flag? I understand the main security concern is XSS attacks. So since Javascript can access the cookie, attackers can potentially access the token. But since there isn't any sensitive info in the JWT, is the only harm session hijacking?

The crux of the issue is that I would like the JWT to be in a Javascript-accessible cookie because I want to be able to access the token claims to limit the functionality of the user within the ui.

So is it a better idea to use a **non**-httponly cookie for the JWT, or make the JWT in a httponly cookie and just do a separate **non**-httponly cookie for storing the user's credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Although the JWT does not *contain* any sensitive information, the *token itself* is sensitive. JWTs are usually used as bearer tokens, which means they are a (possibly time limited) credential that can be used by anyone in possession of the token to access whatever resources the token is issued for.

An attacker who was able to obtain the token via a successful XSS would therefore be able to impersonate the victim to make requests to your server. This is what you describe as "only" session hijacking. I'm not sure why you say "only". Usually session hijacking is pretty serious ;o)

A more secure approach in my opinion, as you say, to make the JWT cookie HTTP-Only and have a separate cookie containing the information used to limit the functionality in the UI.

As an aside, limiting the UI in this way should not be considered as an effective security measure on it's own, since it would almost certainly be possible to bypass the UI restrictions unless they were also enforced on the server side. It is fine to use it for **personalisation** of the UI though.